# Firebase Realtime Database overwrites old data while adding new

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hi there i'm facing issue that FB realtime DB deletes old data while inserting a new one here is my code

```
 String text = reviewText.getText().toString();
                if (text.length() > 15){
                    int rating = (int) ratingBar.getRating();
                    String uuid = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                    Map<String, String> data = new HashMap();
                    data.put("rating", String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(rating))));
                    data.put("comment", text);
                    DatabaseReference  db = firebaseDatabase.getReferenceFromUrl("dburl").child("attr_reviews").child(placename);
                    db.setValue(uuid).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                db.child(uuid).setValue(data).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                        if (task.isSuccessful()){

                                        }else {
                                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.eReviewErrUnkw, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            }else {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.eReviewErrUnkw, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });

                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.eReviewErrTxt, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
```

I have tried to put push() into diffrent positions but still same.
DB structure looks like this
It should create DB structure like this on image

[image]

Edit:
Database structure should look like this

```
enter code here
DB
 └attr_reviews
             └city1
                  └useruuid1
                           └comment: ""
                           └rating: x
                  └useruuid2
                           └....
            └city2
                 └....
```

Comment: Changing the db reference didn't work?

Comment: It writes data, but not how it's supposed to be, it delete all other childs (other uuids as well with comment and rating)

Comment: As a temporary fix you could retrieve the previous values before you push and push everything in on the next push.

Comment: Where have you reached on this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this way you stop at "Sarajevo"

```
DatabaseReference  db = firebaseDatabase.getReferenceFromUrl("dburl").child("attr_reviews").child(placename);
//Sarajevo
// ==> PUSHING VALUES
                    db.setValue(uuid).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() { ...
```

I think you should go down nesting. Something like

```
DatabaseReference  db = firebaseDatabase.getReferenceFromUrl("dburl").child("attr_reviews").child(placename).child(userid);
```

Comment: Thank's on help this is what i needed

Answer (score 0):

The data in the database is getting overwritten, what you need to do is use `push()` which would create a random id for you in the database:

```java
db.child(uuid).push().setValue(data).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
```

This way you will have the following database:

```
uuid
  random-id1
       comment: "comment"
       rating: 1
  random-id2
       comment: "comment"
       rating: 1
```

Comment: This  example above isn't working properly,  https://imgur.com/ovEUXeM data deleted after inserting a new one

Comment: It's getting deleted because of the first `setValue` that you are doing. Is uuid equal to Sarajevo?

Comment: Nah, Sarajevo isn't UUID, Sarajevo is city name, like many other, this cities should have child UserUUID, which represents user review and contains Review, and Rating. Sarajevo should contain childs with UUID

Comment: remove the first setvalue `db.setValue(uuid).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {` it is not needed

Comment: It's needed beacuse user UUID dont exist as child, and it's needed later to check did user gave review